# T distribution formula for Percent Point Function

Tags: python, c++, scipy, statistics, distribution

I used python scipy library to get the ppf value. I am trying to calculate  the ppf in c++ without using python. I went through many articles online but couldn't find one. Can any one help me to get ppf in c++.

In python:

```py
>>> from scipy.stats import t
>>> t.ppf(0.75,29)
0.6830438592467807
```

Likewise,
In c++ I want a function passing two variables (0.75,29) and return the ppf value 0.6830438592467808 .

Answer (score 5):

The boost library contains all you need to compute quantiles (aka percent point function).

A possible implementation:

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/students_t.hpp>

double ppf(double q, double df) {
    boost::math::students_t dist(df);
    return boost::math::quantile(dist, q);
}
```

See also this godbolt [link](https://godbolt.org/z/KhW35zW8v).

Reference links:
[scipy's student t](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html), [boost's student t](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/students_t_dist.html), [boost's quantile](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/nmp.html#math_toolkit.dist_ref.nmp.quantile)